# More than one extra using flickr.photo.search

Tags: python, flickr

```
photo_list = flickr.photos.search(api_key=api_key, accuracy = 15, has_geo=1, per_page = 500, extras = 'tags', 'url_s')
```

I want to do the following search using the Flickr API. It works fine when I call just one extra, either tags, or URL. However if I try to get it to return both it does not work. On [this page for this particular API](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html), its says to use a comma-delimited list of extra information to fetch for each returned record, which is what I thought I was already doing, but it is not working.

Any suggestions on how I can call both?

Comment: If you've found the answer acceptable, you should mark it as answered. I've noticed in your profile you don't often mark them as accepted. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3):

The way you are passing the 'url_s' parameter has python interpreting it as a separate parameter to the function, try using

```
photo_list = flickr.photos.search(api_key=api_key, accuracy = 15, has_geo=1, per_page = 500, extras = 'tags,url_s')
```